# Creating responsive flexbox layout containing images in a certain pattern

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive layout containing images using flexbox. I have achieved the pattern that I want to but it is not responsive. Following is the pattern:

https://jsfiddle.net/wcep5tuk/16/embedded/result/

Even though the pattern looks okay, upon resizing the window, everything falls apart.Here's my css:

```
.my-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.left-flex-container {
  width: 59.4%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right-flex-container {
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
}

div.left-flex-container>img,
div.right-flex-container>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and my html

```
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="left-flex-container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/789x330" alt="">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/306x228" alt="">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/481x228" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right-flex-container">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/440x565" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wcep5tuk/16/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your code i assume that you need those boxes to be responsive (stretch or shrink).

Here is CSS:

```
.my-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
  }

  .left-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }

  .right-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }

  div.left-flex-container>img,
  div.right-flex-container>img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

In this scenario you don't need to add height to every box. Images inside Div or box sets box/total height.
Fixed width causes spaces between boxes which makes it seems less responsive.

If You want to move right section below the left section on small screens you'll have to use media rules with `flex-flow:column wrap` in `.my-container` class.

**Remember**: *Flex-Box only work on Parent-child case, not on parent-descendants!*

https://jsfiddle.net/7pmL9wpv/

Hope This Helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is not the pattern that I was looking for. The one that I want is this: https://jsfiddle.net/wcep5tuk/16/embedded/result/  . What I did was to divide the container in 2 parts, the left containing 3 images with one being on top(due to flex-wrap:wrap) and 2 on the bottom. The right-flex-container's height should always be equal to the left-flex-container's, thus, maintaining a box like structure. I want the pattern to scale up and down as a whole.

Comment: @JohnSmith:  remove `flex-flow` property from right container.
https://jsfiddle.net/7pmL9wpv/4/

Comment: Again, this is not the pattern that I want to achieve. The pattern that I want to make responsive is this one:  https://jsfiddle.net/wcep5tuk/16/embedded/result/